# Formula 1: the lowest-ranked driver to win the Drivers' Championship in the final race?

Tags: trivia, history, ranking, formula-1, auto-racing

At the start of the 2007 season final at Brazil, Kimi Raikkonen was third in the Drivers' Championship table behind Lewis Hamilton and Fernando Alonso.

He went on to win the Championship by one point. It was only the second time (Giuseppe Farina in 1950) that this has occurred.

Has there been an instance where a driver ranked outside the top three at the start of the final race, then won that Drivers' Championship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It has never happened that a driver who was 4th or further before the last race has won the Formula 1 Driver's Championship.**

Below, you can find a list of situations in which the winner had a reduced point margin.

These are the years where the Driver Champion won within 25 points:

1. [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Formula_One_World_Championship) Rosberg wins by 5 points  but was already leading before the last race
2. [2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Formula_One_season) Vettel wins by 3 points but lead since last 4 races
3. **[2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Formula_One_season) Vettel wins by 4 points and starts the last races from 3rd position in Driver ranking**

Before 2010 the winner took 10 points (or less):

1. [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Formula_One_season) Hamilton wins by 1 point starting last race as a leader (I remember an incredible last lap where Hamilton take the point to win the title)
2. **[2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_Formula_One_season) as quoted in the question, Raikkonnen wins the title by 1 point starting the last race from 3rd position in Driver rankings**
3. [2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_Formula_One_season) Schumacher wins by 2 points starting last race as a leader
4. [1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Formula_One_season) Häkkinen wins by 2 points starting last race as a leader
5. [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Formula_One_season) Schumacher wins by 1 point starting last race as a leader (Schumacher and Hill retired because of a collision in last race)
6. [1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_Formula_One_season) Senna wins by 7 points starting last race as a leader
7. [1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_Formula_One_season) Senna wins by 3 points starting last race as a leader
8. **[1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_Formula_One_season) Prost wins by 2 points starting last race from 2nd position**
9. [1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_Formula_One_season) Laura wins by 0.5 points starting last race as a leader
10. **[1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1983_Formula_One_season) Piquet wins by 2 points starting last race from 2nd position**
11. **[1981](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1981_Formula_One_season) Piquet wins by 1 point starting last race from 2nd position**
12. [1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1979_Formula_One_season) Scheckter wins by 4 points starting last race as a leader
13. **[1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Formula_One_season) Hunt wins by 1 point starting last race from 2nd position**
14. [1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_Formula_One_season) Fittipaldi wins by 3 points starting last race as a co-leader
15. [1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_Formula_One_season) Rindt wins by 5 points not racing last 4 races
16. [1697](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1967_Formula_One_season) Hulme wins by 5 points starting last race as a leader
17. **[1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_Formula_One_season) Surtees wins by 1 point starting last race from 2nd position**
18. [1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1961_Formula_One_season) Hill wins by 1 points not racing last race as a leader
19. [1960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1960_Formula_One_season) Brabham wins by 9 points starting last race as a leader
20. [1959](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1959_Formula_One_season) Brabham wins by 4 points starting last race as a leader
21. [1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_Formula_One_season) Hawthorn wins by 1 point starting last race as a leader
22. 1956 Fangio wins by 3 points starting last race as a leader
23. [1953](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Formula_One_season) Ascari wins by 6.5 points starting last race as a leader
24. **[1951](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1951_Formula_One_season) Fangio wins by 6 points starting last race from 2nd position**
25. **[1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_Formula_One_season) Farina wins by 3 points starting last race from 2nd position**